# Randomizing set of elements in java

Tags: java, database

I am trying to populate around 10000 rows in my database in a java application. I am able to choose random firstNames, LastNames etc. I have set of 60 {Departmentid, Managerid} combinations. I have to randomly assign this set to those 10,000 employees. Every employee should have a legitimate Departmentid and Managerid combination.

How should I approach this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically, I have to randomize combinations of {Departmentid, Managerid} and yes no Managerid should have more than 15 employees

Answer (score 2):

If your departmentId or managerids are stored in arrays, you can use the java.util.Random 
    `departmentid[new Random().nextInt(60)]` where nextInt(int upperbound) will help randomize the entries.

Comment: DepartmentId, ManagerId should be from those 60 combinations. This approach generates some other answers too. My apologies if I am not getting your approach right.

Comment: The arrays departmentId[] and managerid[]  will be used in your insert query for the database.  Are there 60 managers and departments ? in any case all you have to do is alter the upper-bound.

Comment: yes, they would be used in insert query. I will take them from other table which has this combination in each row. there are 6 departments and 60 managers, each manager belongs to certain department. So manager, department combination should exist. I just tried the way you suggested. How do I validate that the combination is valid before inserting.

Comment: you can have a validator with contain your validation rules (particular combinations or exceptional conditions). Validator will return a boolean which will be the trigger for the retry logic.

Comment: Thank you sir, I think that would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is the easiest way. Create a hash of combination of first and last name.
Now take a random hash and find the employee for that hash and assign whatever u want